# Gatsby Develop works, Gatsby Build fails: Loader to handle File Type Missing

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

First off, I'm new to React/Gatsby. I'm not new to Jekyll, Lando, Drupal, WordPress, basic Git, HTML5/CSS3. I am not strong with JS. Ok, that's out of the way.

I've a got a simple one page site (splash page) that will evolve into a multi-page site. I decided to try Gatsby. The `gatsby develop` command works well, and I have no es-lint errors for unused variables and such. The `gatsby build` command produces an error that seems like a super basic thing. There are only two pages in the site — a 404 page and an index. If I remove the 404 page, I get the same error on the index page. Gatsby/Webpack seems to choke on the first piece of content being passed:

```
JHogue:civicpolicy jhogue$ gatsby build
success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.006 s
success load plugins — 0.131 s
success onPreInit — 0.166 s
success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.008 s
success initialize cache — 0.006 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.068 s
success onPreBootstrap — 0.006 s
success source and transform nodes — 0.048 s
success building schema — 0.154 s
success createPages — 0.000 s
success createPagesStatefully — 0.024 s
success onPreExtractQueries — 0.000 s
success update schema — 0.085 s
success extract queries from components — 0.050 s
success run graphql queries — 0.022 s — 4/4 197.54 queries/second
success write out page data — 0.003 s
success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
success onPostBootstrap — 0.001 s

info bootstrap finished - 3.259 s

error Generating JavaScript bundles failed

  Error: ./.cache/async-requires.js 8:11
  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:11)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  | exports.components = {
  |   "component---src-pages-404-js": function componentSrcPages404Js() {
  >     return import("/Users/jhogue/github/civicpolicy/src/pages/404.js"
  |     /* webpackChunkName: "component---src-pages-404-js" */
  |     );
   @ ./.cache/production-app.js 18:0-45 21:23-36 26:23-36
```

Since it is just a splash page, there are no data feeds, no markdown files, no arrays of pages to iterate over. Its very simple.

My dependency list is as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.0.117",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.10",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.20",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.1.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.2.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2"
  }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change/modify your webpack config? Is it possible to see your repo?

Comment: Right now, no… the project is in a private repo. I have a `gatsby-config.js` file, `gatsby-node.js` file, and a `package.json`. No web pack config that I am aware of. The starter theme that I was using did not have one. I used Serif: https://github.com/jugglerx/gatsby-serif-theme. When I run `gatsby build` inside that repo unmodified, the build works.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a Node version issue. Gatsby recommends Node 8 or higher. Can you run `node --version` and see if you're using a high enough Node version?

If you need a newer version of Node, [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a great way to make switching Node versions easier.

Comment: ````$ node --version
v11.7.0````
Hmmm. So, no dice there.

Comment: If worse comes to worse, since this is a simple splash page, can I host on Github pages with the content of the public folder when running `gatsy develop`?

Comment: Any additional insights here @jlengstorf? I'm still stuck.

Comment: Did you try deleting your `.cache`?

Comment: Yep, several times. Thanks @Zlatev

Comment: @J.Hogue any chance you can share the source so I can test it locally? Make sure all your dependencies are up to the latest version (there was an upstream issue earlier this month that _might_ be behind this) and potentially try deleting `node_modules`, `yarn.lock`/`package-lock.json`, `.cache`, and `public` to see if a fresh install makes any difference.

Comment: I did all that previously, but here I am, 10 days later, and I do it all again. This time it works. I'm still in Gatsby 2.4.8 but some node dependency must have changed. Granted, a few assets in the public build are not loading but I can probably figure that out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great news! Thanks for following up.